# Multiple Shiny apps in ioslide presentations

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, ioslides

I am trying to develop my class lecture slides using Shiny apps and ioslides.  I would like to have several Shiny apps, each on a different slide to illustrate different concepts.  When I naively write the input and render code for an app on a slide, only the first app works and the succeeding apps do not work.

Do I have to shut down the first app before starting the second (and so forth)? I can't seem to find an answer anywhere and I hope someone here can lead me in the right direction. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Never mind.   I seem to have figured out what was wrong.

Comment: You should indicate what was wrong to help anyone else who is having a similar issue in the future.

Comment: I tried to write two Shiny apps on two adjacent slides.   As I flipped through the slides, app 1 always worked, and when I got to the second slide app 2 never worked.   If I flipped through the slides in reverse, app 1 worked.  The problem was the template that I was using for the Shiny apps.   Both now work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently and what you have to avoid its to think you are making differente shiny app in the same presentation, because the hole documen its a shiny runtime. Here you do not have to create explicitly the objects "ui" and "serve"

Look at this example to see if you can get the idea

````
    ---
    title: "Shiny app - stackoverflow help"
    author: "Johan Rosa"
    date: "August 8, 2018"
    output: ioslides_presentation
    runtime: shiny
    ---   
     ## first slide
                    
        ```{r}
        fluidPage(
           
           # Application title
           titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
           
           # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
           sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                 sliderInput("bins",
                             "Number of bins:",
                             min = 1,
                             max = 50,
                             value = 30)
              ),
              
              # Show a plot of the generated distribution
              mainPanel(
                 plotOutput("distPlot")
              )
           )
        )
        ```


    
        ```{r}
        output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
              # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
              x    <- faithful[, 2] 
              bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
              
              # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
              hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
           })
        ```

## next slide

#The other app you want toy show, just the way i did it in the first slide
````

Comment: Thanks for your help.   This is exactly how I fixed my slides (see above, 8/11).